# C-SERVER : sizeof() measures top declared thing. not the new

Tags: c

Above the: **int main()** is:

```
char response[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n";
```

I want to attach string "**oooo**" to this before sending it to client.

```
sprintf(response, "%s %s", response, "oooo");
write(client_fd, response, sizeof(response) - 1);
```

Problem is : **sizeof(response)** is using the **sizeof** the **top "response[]"**

not the size of newly created **response** with  **sprintf()**

as a result, all that gets sent to client is the original **response** not the one with "**oooo**" attached to it.

**Solution = ?**

C-SERVER:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <err.h>

char response[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n";

int main()
{
  int one = 1, client_fd;
  struct sockaddr_in svr_addr, cli_addr;
  socklen_t sin_len = sizeof(cli_addr);

  int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sock < 0)
    err(1, "can't open socket");

  setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &one, sizeof(int));

  int port = 84;
  svr_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  svr_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  svr_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

  if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &svr_addr, sizeof(svr_addr)) == -1) {
    close(sock);
    err(1, "Can't bind");
  }

  listen(sock, 5);
  while (1) {
    client_fd = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &sin_len);

    printf("----\n");

    sprintf(response, "%s %s", response, "oooo");

    write(client_fd, response, sizeof(response) - 1);
    close(client_fd);
  }
}
```

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *7.21.6.6 The sprintf function 2
[...] If
copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.* Also, undefined behavior for accessing outside the bounds of an object.

Comment: Your comment _'not the size of newly created response with `sprintf()`'_ shows a fundamental misunderstanding of what `sprintf()` does.  And trying to overwrite the response array as shown is fundamentally flawed; it is undefined behaviour for simply using `response` as both a source and the target, and there isn't space in the array for what was there before and what you're trying to add, so if it 'worked', it would be writing out of bounds.  Also, `sizeof` is a compile-time constant in this context; it doesn't change.

Comment: Does anyone have some solution to this problem ? I understand C works differently than PHP and stuff..

Comment: Do you have [`asprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) available?  If so, use it: `char *ext; int nbytes; if ((nbytes = asprintf(&ext, "%s %s", response, "oooo")) > 0) { write(client_fd, ext, nbytes); free(ext); }`.

Answer (score 2):

```
char response[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n";
```

Okay, the above line declares a 20-byte char array (19 ASCII characters plus the implicit terminating NUL byte).

> Problem is : sizeof(response) is using the sizeof the top "response[]"

sizeof(response) returns the size of the array.  In C, arrays are fixed-length; their size cannot change.

```
sprintf(response, "%s %s", response, "oooo");
```

This cannot work, for the reasons @EOF mentioned in his comment:  first, you are trying to fit more than 20 characters into an array that is 20 characters long; that will result in undefined behavior when sprintf() writes past the end of the array.  And second, you are trying to sprintf() response into itself, which isn't a supported thing to do.

> Solution = ?

What you want to do is concatenate a string to the end of the existing string; to do that you will need a larger array.  If you know the lengths of the strings involved at runtime, you could do this:

```
const char response[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n";
const char moreData[] = "oooo";
char biggerResponse[sizeof(response)+sizeof(moreData)-1];  // -1 because we don't need room for both NUL bytes
strcpy(biggerResponse, response);
strcat(biggerResponse, moreData);
write(client_fd, biggerResponse, sizeof(biggerResponse) - 1);
```

If moreData is a string whose length you don't know at compile time, you'll probably have to resort to dynamic allocation to ensure your biggerResponse array is big enough to hold both strings:

```
const char response[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n";
const char * moreData = "some other string whose length we're not sure of";
const size_t biggerResponseSize = sizeof(response)+strlen(moreData);
char * biggerResponse = (char *) malloc(biggerResponseSize);
strcpy(biggerResponse, response);
strcat(biggerResponse, moreData);
write(client_fd, biggerResponse, biggerResponseSize - 1);
free(biggerResponse);
```

Of course, concatenating strings in C is awkward and error-prone, so you might just avoid the whole problem by instead write()-ing the two strings separately:

```
const char response[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n";
const char moreData[] = "oooo";
write(client_fd, response, sizeof(response) - 1);
write(client_fd, moreData, sizeof(moreData) - 1);
```